# Save a range to PDF from Gooogle Sheets App Script using non profit version of Google

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am using a non profit version of Google for a very small organisation where users have very limited technical skills. I have written a script that should save a range from Google Sheets as a PDF in a shared drive but the Script fails due to Drive API limitations according to Gemini.

The need for the script is to ensure that new files are created and saved with a standard naming convention and in specific folders. Is there a way this can be achieved? Upgrading to a paid version is not an option. Does anyone have workaround ideas.

I created a script which would save a PDF File based on a range using cell references to indicate where the file would save to and the name of the file. I checked the code with Gemini and it looked  right, but when I added that I was using the non profit version of Google workspace, I found out that there are Drive API restrictions.

Comment: This is the explanation I get from  Gemini Missing Functionalities:

Drive API Restrictions: The free Google Workspace version restricts access to certain functionalities of the Google Drive API. These limitations include:

Limited File Creation: Scripts cannot directly create new files in shared drives, including PDFs.
Limited File Modifications: Scripts have limited capabilities to modify existing files in shared drives, making it challenging to programmatically generate content and save it as a PDF.

Comment: The code should programattically save a PDF print version of a range with a new name to a folder, but the free version does not allow this.

Comment: The purpose of the script is to take a snapshot of a Google Sheets file and save a range as a PDF file using a new name and saving it to a shared drive. The script fails because Google Non Profit version does not allow the creation of a new file due to security. Does  this explanation help:

Comment: The code fails at the line with this error message 8:14:37 PM Error 
TypeError: doc.setContent(...).saveAndClose is not a function
savePrintRangeToPDF @ Code.gs:65
  // Set the content and save the file 
  doc.setContent(pdfBlob).saveAndClose();